# Constructing a dc circuit with different input and output currents and voltages?

Tags: current

I am trying to answer this question (at the moment I am looking at part a) only as I still have not figured it out):
[image]

But what I do not understand is how you can change the input and output of dc? I undertand the principle behind transformers, but here I just don't know. I am sure it has to do with the other two terminals kept at zero volts, but here is my second problem: I can't see how you could keep something at zero volts without the current flowing down there, from higher to lower potential, and how these terminals at zero volts would be important in the construction of this circuit?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It is not clear to me what types of circuit you are familiar with. As described, the input current does not seem to control the output voltage. If I read that correctly, and since there are "internal power sources" in the box, then a battery in series with a resistor would provide the output; and a large input resistor between input terminals will give a small input current for a certain input voltage (use Ohm's law to compute the values).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Floris. I just think that this is meant to be a single circuit rather than two separate ones. Especially considering the second part. I also do not understand where the zero volts is coming from... Are you suggesting that the 0V is in the terminal just before a battery with internal resistance r, and with a terminal p.d. of Vout across the battery? And this would be the ciircuit on the right hand side, and there would be a separate circuit on the left? The way this question has been presented makes me think that there is something more to this..

Comment: 0 volts is a reference ("ground") which is relative to other parts of the circuit. It might be represented with a ground connection (upside down triangle).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic How do I move my post?

Comment: I believe there _will_ be a return current in the 0V terminals but this is not shown.

Comment: What is the meaning of "p.d" (sorry, but I am not a native english speaker).

Answer (score 1):

(i) What I understand from the circuit is that you have to replace the box in figure with an equivalent circuit.

If Vin is the applied voltage and the current is Iin, we can represent the input port with a resistance whose value is Rin = Vin/Iin. But since Iin is too small, the value of Rin will be very high.

The circuit at output is already given in the question. It is a voltage source and a series resistance. So the very simple circuit that can replace the box given in question is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTMGOX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(ii) When a subsequent resistor R of is connected at the output as shown in figure below,
then

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC1hnM.png)</sup>

$$I_{out} = \frac{V_{out}}{R+r}\tag1$$

and if \$r >> R\$, then we can neglect R and write \$R+r \approx r\$ then 
$$I_{out} = \frac{V_{out}}{r}$$

ie, the output current is independent of the resistor R and the output act as a constant current source, provided the internal resistance r of the circuit is higher than R.

Writing the expression for voltage across R,
$$V_R = I_{out}\times R$$ 
from (1),
$$ V_R = \frac{V_{out}}{R+r} \times R$$
$$= V_{out} \times \frac{1}{1 + r/R}$$

If this should work as a voltage source, then \$V_R\$ should be equal to \$V_{out}\$. Or,
$$ \frac{1}{1 + r/R} = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow r/R << 1$$
Or,
$$r << R$$
ie, the internal resistance should be less than the subsequent resistance.

Read about internal resistance of a [current source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) and [voltage source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source).